# User Leak, libc++ leak or false positive

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, clang, valgrind, libc++

I am building a dynamic library on mac in C++11 using the clang compiler and libc++ standard library. When I run valgrind on my test code which links to my dynamic library I get one block of memory that is definitely lost. Here is the valgrind report:

```
==45659== 36 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 57 of 228
==45659==    at 0x66BB: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:300)
==45659==    by 0x31EAB0: __Balloc_D2A (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==45659==    by 0x31F2A5: __d2b_D2A (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==45659==    by 0x31BED6: __dtoa (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==45659==    by 0x3438A9: __vfprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==45659==    by 0x36A2DA: __v2printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==45659==    by 0x34FF66: _vsnprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==45659==    by 0x34FFC5: vsnprintf_l (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==45659==    by 0x34057A: snprintf_l (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==45659==    by 0x10C75A: std::__1::num_put<char, std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > >::do_put(std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >, std::__1::ios_base&, char, double) const (in /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib)
==45659==    by 0xF3221: std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(double) (in /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib)
==45659==    by 0x12102: lmpsdata::header_data::write_dimension(std::__1::basic_ofstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) (header_data.cpp:75)
==45659== 
==45659== LEAK SUMMARY:
==45659==    definitely lost: 36 bytes in 1 blocks
==45659==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==45659==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==45659==    still reachable: 18,340 bytes in 215 blocks
==45659==         suppressed: 25,274 bytes in 374 blocks
```

That particular section of code does not deal with any memory I have dynamically allocated, only STL objects and streams are used. I have attached both the header file and the method reported by valgrind as causing the leak. Can someone please explain what is going on here? I am absolutely baffled.

header_data.h

```
    #ifndef ____header_data__
#define ____header_data__

#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

namespace lmpsdata {
class header_data
{//LAMMPS header information
    //only the point particle header information has been implemented
    //since the current atom base class is designed for point particles only
public:
    header_data():xdim(2), ydim(2), zdim(2), tiltdim(3) {}
    //methods
    void read(const std::string &, const std::string &);
    void write(std::ofstream &, const std::string &); //this write command will replace the one
    std::string check_header_keyword(const std::string &, bool &);
    uint64_t get(const std::string&);
    std::vector<double>& get_vector(const std::string&);
    void set(const std::string&, uint64_t);
    void set_vector(const std::string&, std::vector<double>&);

private:
    //methods
    void read_dimension(const std::string&, const std::string&);
    void write_dimension(std::ofstream&, const std::string&);

    //members
    uint64_t atomnum;
    uint64_t bondnum;
    uint64_t anglenum;
    uint64_t dihedralnum;
    uint64_t impropernum;
    uint64_t atomtypenum;
    uint64_t bondtypenum;
    uint64_t angletypenum;
    uint64_t dihedraltypenum;
    uint64_t impropertypenum;
    uint64_t extrabondnum;

    std::vector<double> xdim;
    std::vector<double> ydim;
    std::vector<double> zdim;
    std::vector<double> tiltdim;//for use with triclinic system

    std::map<std::string, uint64_t&> int_map  {
        {"atoms", atomnum},
        {"bonds", bondnum},
        {"angles", anglenum},
        {"dihedrals", dihedralnum},
        {"impropers", impropernum},
        {"atom types", atomtypenum},
        {"bond types", bondtypenum},
        {"angle types", angletypenum},
        {"dihedral types", dihedraltypenum},
        {"improper types", impropertypenum},
        {"extra bond per atom", extrabondnum},
    };
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<double>&> v_map {
        {"xlo xhi", xdim},
        {"ylo yhi", ydim},
        {"zlo zhi", zdim},
        {"xy xz yz", tiltdim}
    };
};
}
#endif /* defined(____header_data__) */
```

lmpsdata.cpp only write_dimension method and beginning of file is shown

```
#include "header_data.h"
#include <stdexcept>
using namespace lmpsdata;
void header_data::write_dimension(std::ofstream &file, const std::string& keyword)
{
    std::vector<double>& data = v_map.at(keyword);
    for (auto value: data) {
        file << value <<  " ";
    }
}
```

If more information is needed please let me know.

Comment: Have you made sure that the ofstream you pass into `header_data::write_dimension()` is correctly closed and deleted afterwards? Also, have you tried splitting the statement `file << value << " ";` into multiple statements and lines, to find out if the problem is related to the ofstream or to the formatting command? Also, are you using a recent Valgrind version?

Comment: The valgrind report above occurs with both ostream closed and left open. The first time I ran valgrind, I had forgotten to close the stream and I thought that was the issue. The issue still persisted though.

Comment: I am using valgrind-3.10.1. I will check the formatting later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not mentioned the exact versions of OSX and valgrind that you're using.  I've not been able to entirely reproduce this on the version that I'm using (OSX 10.10; valgrind HEAD==Valgrind-3.11.0.SVN).

This is not in the `C++` standard library, but in the `C` library. You should be able to reproduce it (almost identically) with the simple code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <xlocale.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    locale_t loc = newlocale(LC_NUMERIC_MASK, "C", (locale_t)0);
    double d = 22.22;
    char buffer[1024];
    snprintf_l(buffer, 1024, loc, "%f\n", d);
    printf("%s", buffer);
    freelocale(loc);
}
```

When run with `valgrind --show-leak-kinds=all --leak-check=full ./leak` I see some 'still reachable' leaks (yours should show actual leaks in this case):

```
==26151== 32 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 28 of 85
==26151==    at 0x10000850B: malloc (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/HEAD/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==26151==    by 0x1002BC7DF: __Balloc_D2A (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==26151==    by 0x1002B9533: __rv_alloc_D2A (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==26151==    by 0x1002B9B3A: __dtoa (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==26151==    by 0x1002E1D52: __vfprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==26151==    by 0x10030A9AE: __v2printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==26151==    by 0x1002EF154: _vsnprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==26151==    by 0x1002EF1B3: vsnprintf_l (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==26151==    by 0x1002DF5F7: snprintf_l (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==26151==    by 0x100000ECA: main (leak.cpp:10)
==26151== 
==26151== 36 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 30 of 85
==26151==    at 0x10000850B: malloc (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/HEAD/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==26151==    by 0x1002BC7DF: __Balloc_D2A (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==26151==    by 0x1002BD055: __d2b_D2A (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==26151==    by 0x1002B986B: __dtoa (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==26151==    by 0x1002E1D52: __vfprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==26151==    by 0x10030A9AE: __v2printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==26151==    by 0x1002EF154: _vsnprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==26151==    by 0x1002EF1B3: vsnprintf_l (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==26151==    by 0x1002DF5F7: snprintf_l (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==26151==    by 0x100000ECA: main (leak.cpp:10)
==26151== 
==26151== 80 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 47 of 85
==26151==    at 0x10000850B: malloc (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/HEAD/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==26151==    by 0x1002BC736: __Balloc_D2A (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==26151==    by 0x1002BD055: __d2b_D2A (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==26151==    by 0x1002B986B: __dtoa (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==26151==    by 0x1002E1D52: __vfprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==26151==    by 0x10030A9AE: __v2printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==26151==    by 0x1002EF154: _vsnprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==26151==    by 0x1002EF1B3: vsnprintf_l (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==26151==    by 0x1002DF5F7: snprintf_l (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==26151==    by 0x100000ECA: main (leak.cpp:10)
```

I'd put in a suppression for it, as it's almost undoubtably not a real leak and is completely out of your control.

looking at the published [OSX libc source](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/), I can't see where the bug is present - 320 and later all look OK; with the underlying code appearing to allocate and free where necessary. The bug may have been introduced and fixed, though, as I didn't perform an exhaustive trawl of all the sources; the file in question is [vfprintf.c](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-320/stdio/FreeBSD/vfprintf.c), you're looking at the `dtoaresult` assignments & frees.

To determine your version of libc, you can do:

```
$ otool -l /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib | grep -A5 ID_
```

On my system I get the output:

```
          cmd LC_ID_DYLIB
      cmdsize 64
         name /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 1 Thu Jan  1 01:00:01 1970
      current version 1044.10.1
compatibility version 1.0.0
```

997, I think, is mavericks (10.9). I don't know if they introduced a leak in the code at some point in the mavericks timeframe and then fixed it - there doesn't appear to be a code path in the `__vfprintf` routine that actually leaks in any of the published source.

Comment: I am in mavericks (10.9), the version of libsystem_c.dylib is 997.90.3. When I run the code in valgrind I am not getting any definitely lost leaks just 4 still reachable and they are the same as yours. I think your right this is probably not a real leak. I wonder if this is an issue with valgrind-3.10.1 and C++11.

Comment: It could easily be an issue with valgrind 3.10.1 misreporting the leak because it can't track the allocation properly - I've seen a few of these and generally the system-level suppression file is used to prevent these leaks from being reported.

Comment: Thanks I'll look into how to set up a suppression file.

Comment: Pass in --gen-suppressions=yes to get a corresponding suppression, and remove lines coming from the your code directly to make it a little bit more recyclable if it appears under different code paths