# C++ dynamic array of doubles leaks according to valgrind, why?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind, dynamic-arrays

I wrote this dummy program to help me understand the output of Valgrind I get for another larger program. However, I cannot find out why for this program Valgrind tells me that 80 bytes are "definitely lost". As far as I have read online this is the correct way to allocate and delete dynamic arrays. Am I doing it wrong?
Furthermore, since my array is 5*[double] = 40 bytes long and there are only three other int variables I also do not see where 80 bytes can possibly come from.

Below are the code, the commands I used to compile and run with Valgrind and the output of Valgrind.

```
int main(){
    int N = 5;
    double* array = new double[N];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        array[i] = 0.5;
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
        cout << "array[" << j << "] = " << array[j] << endl;
    }

    delete[] array;

    return 0;
}
```

Commands to compile and run with Valgrind:

```
g++-5 -std=c++11 main.cpp
valgrind --leak-check=yes ./a.out
```

Valgrind output:

```
==1511== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==1511== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==1511== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==1511== Command: ./a.out
==1511== 
array[0] = 0.5
array[1] = 0.5
array[2] = 0.5
array[3] = 0.5
array[4] = 0.5
==1511== 
==1511== HEAP SUMMARY:
==1511==     in use at exit: 99,219 bytes in 200 blocks
==1511==   total heap usage: 262 allocs, 62 frees, 104,939 bytes allocated
==1511== 
==1511== 148 (80 direct, 68 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 43 of 68
==1511==    at 0x100008EBB: malloc (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/3.11.0/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==1511==    by 0x1004698D6: __Balloc_D2A (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==1511==    by 0x10046A21F: __d2b_D2A (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==1511==    by 0x100466877: __dtoa (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==1511==    by 0x10048F3E6: __vfprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==1511==    by 0x1004B86C8: __v2printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==1511==    by 0x10049C914: _vsnprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==1511==    by 0x10049C9C9: vsnprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==1511==    by 0x10006335F: std::__convert_from_v(int* const&, char*, int, char const*, ...) (in /usr/local/Cellar/gcc5/5.2.0/lib/gcc/5/libstdc++.6.dylib)
==1511==    by 0x1000989CF: std::num_put<char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::do_put(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, char, double) const (in /usr/local/Cellar/gcc5/5.2.0/lib/gcc/5/libstdc++.6.dylib)
==1511==    by 0x10014393F: ??? (in /dev/ttys001)
==1511==    by 0x1000A4ECB: std::ostream& std::ostream::_M_insert<double>(double) (in /usr/local/Cellar/gcc5/5.2.0/lib/gcc/5/libstdc++.6.dylib)
==1511== 
==1511== 2,064 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 61 of 68
==1511==    at 0x10000917C: malloc_zone_malloc (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/3.11.0/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==1511==    by 0x10079FEFD: _objc_copyClassNamesForImage (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==1511==    by 0x100793182: protocols() (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==1511==    by 0x100793093: readClass(objc_class*, bool, bool) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==1511==    by 0x100790C13: gc_init (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==1511==    by 0x10079824E: objc_initializeClassPair_internal(objc_class*, char const*, objc_class*, objc_class*) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==1511==    by 0x1007A5132: layout_string_create (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==1511==    by 0x10079383C: realizeClass(objc_class*) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==1511==    by 0x100793300: copySwiftV1MangledName(char const*, bool) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==1511==    by 0x1007932E9: copySwiftV1MangledName(char const*, bool) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==1511==    by 0x1007932E9: copySwiftV1MangledName(char const*, bool) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==1511==    by 0x1007932E9: copySwiftV1MangledName(char const*, bool) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==1511== 
==1511== LEAK SUMMARY:
==1511==    definitely lost: 80 bytes in 1 blocks
==1511==    indirectly lost: 68 bytes in 2 blocks
==1511==      possibly lost: 2,064 bytes in 1 blocks
==1511==    still reachable: 76,800 bytes in 2 blocks
==1511==         suppressed: 20,207 bytes in 194 blocks
==1511== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==1511== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==1511== 
==1511== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==1511== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 18 from 18)
```

Comment: The output of valgrind makes no mention of your dynamic array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [User Leak, libc++ leak or false positive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29442597/user-leak-libc-leak-or-false-positive)

Comment: So I can probably ignore this? I was just wondering since on the valgrind website it says " "definitely lost": your program is leaking memory -- fix it! ".

Comment: No, I haven't. I will check that out. Thank you!